# How to set multiple spans on a TextView's text on the same partial text?

Tags: android, font-size, spannablestring

Suppose I have the next text :

> Hello stackOverflow

And I wish to set the second word to be both [RelativeSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html) (to set a relative font size) and [TextAppearanceSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html) (to set the color of the text) , how do I merge them both ?

All I know is that I can choose one of them , using the next code for example :

```
final SpannableString textToShow = new SpannableString("Hello stackOverflow");
textToShow.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), textToShow.length() - "stackOverflow".length(),textToShow.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(textToShow);
```

But I need to also set the color , or even add other features from other spanning classes ...

What can I do ?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953808

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Simply set additional spans. They are going to overlap/merge when neccessary. This code works for me:

```
final SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hello stackOverflow");
text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), text.length() - "stackOverflow".length(), text.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 3, text.length() - 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(text);
```

Comment: @Zielony What if I have made a new class ? Should it expand ReplacementSpan or something else, so that I will be able to put multiple of them on the same text?

Comment: As far as I know, the algorithm doesn't care about the types

Comment: A detailed example can be found in this [link](https://medium.com/@joseph.neeraj/android-spannable-string-example-864d4e7193bf)

Comment: Also note that `ClickableSpan` won't work without `textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()`

Answer (score 43):

I know this a new reply to an already answered question but I'd like to share a utility class I made which makes this task easier.

---

## Java Version

```
public class SimpleSpanBuilder {
    private class SpanSection{
        private final String text;
        private final int startIndex;
        private final CharacterStyle[] styles;

        private SpanSection(String text, int startIndex,CharacterStyle... styles){
            this.styles = styles;
            this.text = text;
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
        }

        private void apply(SpannableStringBuilder spanStringBuilder){
            if (spanStringBuilder == null) return;
            for (CharacterStyle style : styles){
                spanStringBuilder.setSpan(style, startIndex, startIndex + text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<SpanSection> spanSections;
    private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public SimpleSpanBuilder(){
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        spanSections = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public SimpleSpanBuilder append(String text,CharacterStyle... styles){
        if (styles != null && styles.length > 0) {
            spanSections.add(new SpanSection(text, stringBuilder.length(),styles));
        }
        stringBuilder.append(text);
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleSpanBuilder appendWithSpace(String text,CharacterStyle... styles){
        return append(text.concat(" "),styles);
    }

    public SimpleSpanBuilder appendWithLineBreak(String text,CharacterStyle... styles){
        return append(text.concat("\n"),styles);
    }

    public SpannableStringBuilder build(){
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(stringBuilder.toString());
        for (SpanSection section : spanSections){
            section.apply(ssb);
        }
        return ssb;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
SimpleSpanBuilder ssb = new SimpleSpanBuilder();
ssb.appendWithSpace("Hello");
ssb.append("StackOverflow",new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5));
textView.setText(ssb.build());
```

---

## Kotlin Version

```
class SimpleSpanBuilder() {

    class Span {
        private var startIndex: Int = 0
        internal var text: String
        private var styles: Array<out CharacterStyle>

        internal constructor(index: Int, text: String, vararg styles: CharacterStyle) {
            this.startIndex = index
            this.text = text
            this.styles = styles
        }

        constructor(text: String, vararg styles: CharacterStyle) : this(0, text, *styles)

        internal fun setIndex(index: Int): Span {
            return Span(index, this.text, *this.styles)
        }

        internal fun apply(spanStringBuilder: SpannableStringBuilder?) {
            if (spanStringBuilder == null) return
            for (style in styles) {
                spanStringBuilder.setSpan(
                    style,
                    startIndex,
                    startIndex + text.length,
                    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private val spanSections = mutableListOf<Span>()
    private val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()

    constructor(text: String, vararg styles: CharacterStyle) : this() {
        plus(Span(text, *styles))
    }

    operator fun plus(span: SimpleSpanBuilder.Span): SimpleSpanBuilder {
        spanSections.add(span.setIndex(stringBuilder.length))
        stringBuilder.append(span.text)
        return this
    }

    fun build(): SpannableStringBuilder {
        val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder(stringBuilder.toString())
        for (section in spanSections) {
            section.apply(ssb)
        }
        return ssb
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return stringBuilder.toString()
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var ssb = SimpleSpanBuilder("Hello ",ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE))
ssb += SimpleSpanBuilder.Span(
    "StackOverflow",
    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
    RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f)
)

textView.text = ssb.build()
```

Comment: Also note that `ClickableSpan` won't work without `textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()`

Answer (score 8):

#### Most Easy Way?

#### `textView.setText("I love coding");`

#### `setHighLightedText(textView,"coding");`

Just use below method -

```
public void setHighLightedText(TextView tv, String textToHighlight) {
    String tvt = tv.getText().toString();
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);
    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(tv.getText());

    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            // you can change or add more span as per your need
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), ofe,ofe + textToHighlight.length(), 0); // set size
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), 0);// set color
            tv.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin can help doing this with an extension on `SpannableStringBuilder`:

```
fun SpannableStringBuilder.spansAppend(
    text: CharSequence,
    flags: Int,
    vararg spans: Any
): SpannableStringBuilder {
    val start = length
    append(text)

    spans.forEach { span ->
        setSpan(span, start, length, flags)
    }

    return this
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
builder.append("Start of string ")
builder.spansAppend(
    "text spanned",
    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE,
    RelativeSizeSpan(1.1f),
    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED)
)
```

Comment: Wait, this is an already existing function? Someone wrote me this today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52331300/878126

Comment: Don't know this. inSpan is from Android-KTX https://github.com/android/android-ktx/blob/master/src/main/java/androidx/core/text/SpannableStringBuilder.kt

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample function in Java to append multiple spans at same time:

```
private void append(SpannableStringBuilder builder, CharSequence text, int flags, Object... spans) {
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(text);
    if (spans != null) {
        for (Object span :  spans) {
            if (span != null)
                builder.setSpan(span, start, builder.length(), flags);
        }
    }
}
```

Use this method is simple:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
append(builder, "test", Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE, new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD));
```