# How do I make only one character smaller in an edit text?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

I am making a calculator and I need to add a -1 to the power of cos, to signify inverse cos, and I need to display this in my EditText [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJnSF.jpg). Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Also, I am using Android Studio.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, I didn't find that when I was looking... I tried the way posted there but it didn't work... when I try calling the string from the strings file, I get a null pointer exception

Comment: Ok... I figured the exception out... but when I use the HTML code it doesn't superscript it it just displays the -1 normally

Comment: I figured it out, my case was different because i was using a string builder and that eliminated all html changes

Answer (score 0):

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(Html.fromHtml("cos<sup>-1</sup>"));
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Please add more details in your answer.

Comment: instead of displaying it as a superscript it just displays it normally

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpannableString to customize the text at various points in the strong. 
Please see the following answer for Textview which you can adapt to EditText
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981952/4419474

Comment: Thanks... I used this method and have made the -1 smaller, but it is a subscript not a superscript