# How to set separeted spans on the same textView?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I have a textView and a ListView.
When the user clicks an element of the ListView, it will be added to the textView.
I want to separate these strings on the TV, so when the user clicks on the specified string on the TextView I want to remove that element from the TV.
I think I need SpannableString but I can't separate them from each other. I mean I can't perform different actions on the elements.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qkFx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set multiple spans on a TextView's text on the same partial text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981307/how-to-set-multiple-spans-on-a-textviews-text-on-the-same-partial-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have your `SpannableString`s  you can try to `concat` them using `TextUtils`:

```
TextUtils.concat(span1, span2);
```

And to Create Spans you can use `setSpan` method;

> setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags)

,for Example to Create a `ClickableSpan` you can do this:

```
SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString(Text);
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {

                    }
                };
styledString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, Text.length(), 0);
```

P.S: Remember that you can set multiple span to your Spannable String, just be careful that the end of one span don't overlap the start of next span..

Comment: For example how can I perform action on the second span when it has 6 spans?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above you can have as many SpannableString as you want, 
Also you can set Multiple Span to the same String using setSpan. Each span is created like this: setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags)

So you can even set what part of text is clickable and what part is normal text.