# TextView with different fonts and styles?

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to have texts with different sizes, font-types or styles in the same `TextView` ?

Something like this:

| **myLogin** *logout* |

Comment: Check this link below, it is possible.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533512/1106598

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>myLogin</b> <i>logout</i>"));
```

For more options, look into `SpannableString`: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

With `SpannableString`, you can apply multiple formatting to a single string.

This article will be very helpful to you: [Rich-Style Formatting of an Android TextView](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305055934/http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)

Answer (score 17):

For anyone who wants to do this without the HTML formatting , use a [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

As in :

```
SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString("myLogin logout");
styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 7, 0);
styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 8, 14, 0);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(styledString);
```

More examples can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190301122546/http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)

Answer (score -2):

Unless you make a custom TextView, no. Consider using two different TextViews if you do not want to create a custom TextView.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a custom TextView ?