# Partly editing the text of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

So, let's assume that I want to show a text such as : "**Hello** *stranger* ", using TextView. How would I do that? I realized that I cannot edit only a part of the text in TextView by changing `textStyle` attribute.

Comment: Simply replace the string in your TextView. And use HTML.fromHTML to show the HTML formatted text.

Comment: @KlingKlang I am sorry, but I am relatively new to this. Can you please demonstrate it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: You already know how to use setText(), right? a quick search for `android html textview` will clarify all your doubts. It's very easy to achieve, don't worry. You won't waste a lot of time on this small detail.

Comment: Or... wait, I'll mark your answer as a duplicate, so you can take advantage of the answer in the linked post and we get rid of a duplicate question at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)

Comment: `SpannableString` is also another option. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22420351/9752602)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yourTextViewName.setText(Html.fromHtml(<b>Hello</b> <i>stranger</i>);`

Reference here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler)

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with complexity.  
Place a `TextView` with the uneditable text on the left of the `EditText`.  
 Change the margins and everything that makes it look like a unified view and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the string in string.xml like this
 `<string name="text"><b>Hello</b><i>stranger</i></string>`
and call it in your TextView like `android:text="@string/text"`. It will work for you.