# Can't format action bar Title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

This is probably a really simple question to answer but at the moment I can't sort it.

I have my action set up as follows:

```
// get action bar
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

// set up the action bar layout
final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout,null);

// apply layout
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

I have tried to set up the action bar title as follows:

```
  // setting action bar title
  actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.testing_title));
```

That applies the title correctly, the problem is testing_title is formatted in the strings file as follows:

```
 <string name = "testing_title"><b>Testing</b>Testing</string>
```

So the first 'Testing' should be bold and the second normal.  The problem is that neither are emboldened.  Would anyone know what I should do here?

In my action bar custom layout I had a text view which I was using to display the title and found an answer on here similar to this:

```
  private void setActionBarTitle(String title, ActionBar ab)
    {
        View v = ab.getCustomView();
        TextView titleTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBarTitle);
        titleTxtView.setText(title);
    }
```

I then called this like so:

```
setActionBarTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.audioWalks_title), actionBar);
```

This however didn't produce any results.
If anyone could be on any help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: My first guess - but just a guess - is that the string is interpreted as a string. But if you have a look at [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533512/1798304), you need to use `Html.fromHtml(String)`. So decoding your String and feeding this to the `fromHtml` might work.

Comment: hi thanks for your quick reply, the problem is that I want to keep all my strings in the string.xml and not be creating random strings in different classes.  When I set the text to the text view within the actionbar layout file and set it to @string/...  it kept the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error must be here

```
// setting action bar title
actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.testing_title));
```

The java.lang.String can't contain spans. Try getting the CharSequence reference.

```
actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.testing_title));
```

Comment: Bingo!!  Thank you @Doctoror Drive

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comment, I would recommend to use the `Html.fromHtml(String)` method. You can still keep the Strings in your resource, that's why I said *decode* ;)

So I found something very interessting for you on [android-developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling). If you are not using formatted numbers, you just need to do this:

```
private void setActionBarTitle(String title, ActionBar ab)
{
    View v = ab.getCustomView();
    TextView titleTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBarTitle);
    titleTxtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
private void setActionBarTitle(String title, ActionBar ab)
    {
        View v = ab.getCustomView();
        TextView titleTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBarTitle);
        titleTxtView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        titleTxtView.setText(title);
    }
```

Comment: That method didn't work for me, it just displayed the default application label in the actionbar.  Also I have titles with some of the title embolden.  For example <string name ="china">The <b>Great</b> of China</string>  These will vary from activity/fragment to activity/fragment