# How to use String.format to create a formatted title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550941/cant-format-action-bar-title), and that works fine. But I have a resource string which is a format string that goes into `String.format`.

Consider `R.string.test` to be `This is a test: <b>%1$s</b>`.

Then this code:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(String.format(getString(R.string.test), "TEST"));
```

does not show bold, but this does (but it doesn't show the replaced string obviously):

```
getActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.test));
```

How can I use `String.format` to create a formatted title?

Comment: Use a Spannable to set the text font, the current way you have it, Android will just ignore it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android) on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried `Html.fromHtml`:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#343434>" + "Your Text" + "</font>"));
```

I have another too , this is a `Html` string with multiple space :

```
getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#FFFFFF>" + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" +"Your Text" + "</font>"));
```

Also you can directly go for  :

```
setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#343434>" + "Your Text" + "</font>"));
```

[image]

Comment: i've edited my answer maybe will work for you. Accidently i wrote color like that : ##343434

Comment: Got it. I had to escape the HTML tags in my resources file: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: glad to help your problem, you can create a string in resorces or in hardcoded way. Of course i will suggest resources string.

Answer (score 1):

String.format has this syntax, for example :
String.format("%s %d %f", "string1, myInt, myDouble);
Your variable types and formatting go in the quotes, prefaced by %, then after the quotes and the comma, you add your variables - the must be of the type specified in the quotes, or it will probably crash.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the issue.