# Setting some characters of textview bold

Tags: android, textview

Android Text-view.
Is there any way to change some of the character displayed in a TextView as bold as shown below?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Text" + "<b>" + View + "</b>"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Here you write html formatted text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format text in HTML and show in TextView using following way.

```
String value= "Text" + "<b>" + "View" + "</b>";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take two textview and display your text one is in bold and other is without any effect simple solution.