# how to change background color of selected text in edittext?

Tags: android, textview

How to can I select part of text in a textview or edittext, and change background color of selected text when touch a button?

I want to simulate a marker.
[image]

```
   public class BookViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spannable str;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_list);

        // Get our EditText object.
        final EditText vw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

// Set the EditText's text.
        vw.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.");

// If this were just a TextView, we could do:
// vw.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
// to force it to use Spannable storage so styles can be attached.
// Or we could specify that in the XML.

// Get the EditText's internal text storage
        str = vw.getText();
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), vw.getSelectionStart(), vw.getSelectionEnd(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use `HTML.fromHTML()` and some HTML code.

Comment: @Yasin Kaçmaz can you help me?

Comment: No, he can't, because he didn't post any comment here. So, he will not be notified of your comment.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic I want select part of text in edittext or textview with touch them.

Comment: did not understand. can you elaborate

Comment: do you want to select text on long press on textview ?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic I have a textview or edittext that show some data from database.I want select part of that data and when I selected them,I can set background color the selected text with touch a button.

Comment: @AmitVaghela Such as drag marks on the text of a book

Comment: yes that id exactly what is answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Comment: @AndroidMechanic I want the user to select text,not me

Comment: yes the logic remains the same. get the locations and apply the html for that range which the user selects.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic I can do it.Now How can I save change in database or in app.Is correct if I save str into database ?I edit my Qustion.

Comment: you should post another question as that is a completely different thing