# how to make bold specific text inside string property?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, custom-adapter

I wish to make a specific text bold inside my string which contains many text.. I'm using custom adapter and I'm passing every string to my detail activity. any workaround for this?

```
Practicalities ="Practicalities\n"+ \\I want this to be bold
 "Transportation\nPublic (1)Bus, Buendia to Batangas Port"+
........................................

Registration\n  \\should be bold
Logbook in Malabnig Village\n\n

Guides\n  \\should be bold
Available in Malabnig Village, but not mandatory\n\n

Contact Numbers\n  \\should be bold
None 

Campsites\n  \\should be bold
Front Peak or somewhere near the village\n\n

Water sources\n  \\should be bold
At the starting point of the trail\n\n

Cell phone signal\n  \\should be bold
Yes, Available throughout the hike\n\n
```

[passing data like this :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N99t.png)

Comment: Does the control you're rendering to actually support bolding specific parts of a text string? You didn't post if you're using a label or whatever

Comment: I'm passing those texts in textview xml. I do not know If it supports it.. couldn't find a way

Comment: try the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Comment: doest work for me. what if im passing it like the picture above.. edited*

Comment: was thinking if I could create a string namin in string.xml and pass it inside my object property