# how to set specific language for a word in android string resources file

Tags: java, android, string

I am working with an Android app, which shows some text in Bengali.

This sentence is in the app resources string file:

```
    <resources>
    <string name="sentence">১৯৭৫ সালে বিল গেটস(Bill Gates) এবং পল এলেন(Paul Allen) একসাথে "মাইক্রোসফট"("MicroSoft") নামক কোম্পানি প্রতিষ্ঠা করেন, যেটা পরবর্তীতে পৃথিবীর সবচেয়ে বড় পিসি কোম্পানির মর্যাদা পায়।</string>"
    </resources>
```

I want to show this whole sentence in Bengali, so I set typeface to my textview and I can use different Bengali fonts, but the problem is I need to show names (Bill Gates, Paul Allen and Microsoft) in English instead of Bengali font. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML commands in your text view and then apply different typefaces to different parts of this TextView.

You can do this:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size=... color=... face=...>" + getString(R.string.sentence) + "</font>"))
```

This would set the typeface of the whole sentence to the defined one. To do this only on parts, save the String resource to a local variable, and then apply the different Html commands to the desired parts.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview?rq=1) and for the allowed Html tags [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.de/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)